# fs.watchFile() a json file until a specific value appear

Tags: node.js, json

So I have a json file that changes continously and I need to read it AFTER a value called `auth-token` is written to the file, here what I get now:

```js
const json = fs.readFileSync("some-json.json")
      const headers = JSON.parse(json);
      return headers
```

But it reads the file before anything can be written to it, is there anyway that I can use  `fs.watchFile()` and watch the file UNTIL the value is written?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use `fs.watch` although its behavior is a bit unreliable with multiple events triggered upon file change (but I don't think it would be a problem here).

Here is a small sample:

```
const { watch } = require('fs');
const { readFile } = require('fs/promises');

(async () => {
  const result = await new Promise((resolve) => {
    const watcher = watch('some-json.json', async (eventType, filename) => {
      try {
        const fileContent = await readFile(filename);
        const headers = JSON.parse(fileContent.toString());
        if (headers['auth-token']) { // or whatever test you need here
          watcher.close();
          resolve(headers);
        }
      } catch (e) {}
    });
  });
  console.log(result);
})();
```

Note that if your file gets modified many times before it contains the desired header, it might be preferable to replace the usage of `fs.watch` by a `setInterval` to read the file at regular intervals until it contains the value you expect.

Here is what it would look like:

```
const { readFile } = require('fs/promises');

(async () => {
  const waitingTime = 1000;
  const result = await new Promise((resolve) => {
    const interval = setInterval(async (eventType, filename) => {
      const fileContent = await readFile('some-json.json');
      try {
        const headers = JSON.parse(fileContent.toString());
        if (headers['auth-token']) { // or whatever test you need here
          clearInterval(interval);
          resolve(headers);
        }
      } catch (e) {}
    }, waitingTime);
  });
  console.log(result);
})();
```